# How do I set a color for a function in a callgraph?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

A doxygen callgraph usually colors a single function as gray and all other functions in the call-tree as white. Unfortunately, I need to color several functions in special color for my use case. For example, the following `main.c`

```c
/**
 * @file main.c
*/

/// @brief Foos around
void foo() {}

/// @brief Bars around
void bar() { foo(); }

/// @brief Quux around
void quux() {}

/// @brief System entry point
int main() {
   foo();
   bar();
   quux();
}
```

together with the following Doxygen configuration

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
```

generates  the following tree:

[image: default call graph generation]

While this is fine in general, some internal rules need `bar` to be always colored orange, as it is a "unsafe" function. Similarly, I have to color `foo` as teal to signalize that it is safe. Something I envision is

[image: example call graph]

Is it possible to set the color in Doxygen's generated graphs via Doxygen commands? E.g. some magic command like the non-existing `@dotnodecolor green`? Or do I need to post-process all graphs by hand?

Answer (score 1):

In doxygen there is no way to set the node color, so unfortunately you will have to post process the relevant graphs yourself.

There might be a way around this by redefining the `dot` command (it is a bit mean)

- read the doxygen dot file
- manipulate the required field
- write the file back
- run the real `dot` command.

By means of `doxygen -d extcmd` you can see the used arguments in the call to e.g. `dot`.

For your case te output of the later would be (`DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT = png`):

```
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.dot" -Tpng -o ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.png"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/graph_legend.dot" -Tpng -o "D:/speeltuin/_stack/quest_color_dot/html/graph_legend.png"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.dot" -Tpng -o ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.png"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.map"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.map"`
```

and in case: `DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT = svg`

```
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/graph_legend.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/graph_legend.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/main_8c_a49a4b11e50430aa0a78de989ea99e082_cgraph.map"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/main_8c_ae66f6b31b5ad750f1fe042a706a4e3d4_cgraph.map"`
```